# NGINX proxy_pass does not work; port is not handled in redirect

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

Similar questions appear on this site but I cannot figure this one out. I am running a dockerized config. I can hit my site, `benweaver-VirtualBox:3000/dev/test/rm` successfully.   But I want to be able to hit the site without the port: `benweaver-VirtualBox/dev/test/rm` .

The port does not seem to be handled in my proxy_redirect. I tried commenting out default nginx configuration to no effect. Because I am running a dockerized config I thought the default config may not be relevant anyhow. It is true that a netstat -tlpn |grep :80 does not find nginx.  But docker-compose config has nginx as port 80 both in the container and on export. The config:

```
  server {
    listen 80;
                client_max_body_size 200M;

  location /dev/$NGINX_PREFIX/rm {
    proxy_pass http://$PUBLIC_IP:3000/dev/$NGINX_PREFIX/rm;
```

PUBLIC_IP is set to the hostname of the box: benweaver-VirtualBox.  This hostname is defined in /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   benweaver-VirtualBox
```

I suspect the problem to lie with my hostname.
What config of my hostname, benweaver-VirtualBox, is preventing a successful proxy_pass from a portless URL to benweaver-VirtualBox (127.0.0.1) : 3000    where my app is running?

Answer (score 0):

I got things to work. Here are some take-aways: (1) if you use an address that includes a port, such as my `benweaver-VirtualBox:3000/dev/test/rm` you might not be hitting NGINX at all! Your first step is to make certain you are hitting NGINX; (2) Know how your hosts are associated with ip addresses in the /etc/hosts file. It is ok to associate two or more hostnames with the same numerical ip address; (3) learn about the use of trailing forward slashes in NGINX location expressions. There are two "styles" of writing a URL proxy. In one the writer appends a trailing forward slash onto the end of the location path. Should he or she wish to use location paths in the proxied URL, they must replicate those paths, appending the path elements themselves in the proxy_pass line. Omission of the trailing forward slash ensures that the appending of the location path onto the proxied URL is done automatically